Proposal to award the gold Copy Editor badge multiple times
Nearly four years ago during major updates to  how the review queues worked and following discussion on the matter, we decided to award the gold Steward badge multiple times for any given review queue (such as for Low Quality, Suggested Edits, etc) whenever the next thousand review instances on that queue were hit.
That badge’s description now reads:

Steward
Complete at least 1,000 review tasks. This badge is awarded multiple times per review type. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Because community curation of content is so important in the Stack Exchange model, I propose that we do the same thing with the gold Copy Editor badge, just like we did with Steward. Specifically, we should make it so that the Copy Editor badge can also be awarded multiple times instead of just once. The Copy Editor badge description currently reads:

Copy Editor (current)
Edit 500 posts (excluding own or deleted posts and tag edits).

The only change I am proposing here is for that badge to be awarded at every 500 mark, allowing the description to be updated to say:

Copy Editor (proposed)
Edit at least 500 posts (excluding own or deleted posts and tag edits). This badge can be awarded multiple times.

We should leave the exclusion as is and not change it. But I am not suggesting changing that 500 number, either. After all, content editing is clearly more work than merely approving or rejecting someone else's suggested edit is. Considering that all our sites clearly would benefit with more curation, we should definitely do this.
To make this fair for past curation not just for encouraging future curation, additional Copy Editor badges per 500-edit milestone should be retroactively backfilled as needed the same way we did for Steward four years ago. It “should” not even require much development effort to implement it, given the history doing all this with Steward.

And Illuminator too

Add Marshall to the mix...

This has already been proposed: Allow repeat badges for revisions?

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog No, for many reasons. Just for one, Steward hadn't been done yet. For another, sites were not starting to lack engagement. Now they  certainly are, and so everything has changed. Different world. There isn't enough curation of any sort whatsoever happening any longer. It's unrealistic to pretend that SE today is anything like it was thirteen or fourteen years ago. If you don't react to a changing environment, you perish.

This could lead to more garbage / minor / purely cosmetic edits. Not saying that it will though.

There should be a way to prevent trivial/garbage/bad edits  from occurring especially on those sites where badges are still coveted. Maybe if three or more edits were rolled back by the community, the system could automatically block the editor for, I don't know, a month?

Do you think the low number of effective helpful and useful edits on errors of formatting, spelling, punctuation, weak titles, long naked links etc.  is due to  lack of recognition and not having an extra gold badge? People who care, do and those who don't care or don't have that kind of spare time, don't.

After all, content editing is clearly more work than merely approving or rejecting someone else's suggested edit is. That's definitely not my experience on Stack Overflow, just the opposite. The vast majority of edits are trivial and my edit reviews are very thorough. Perhaps it's different on other sites.

I support changing the badge like this, but I think it would be far more effective to make changes to how editing itself works. Specifically, it should be possible to make a lot of edits without ruining the front page for everyone else. For example, by collapsing all of a single person's edits into a single entry on the front page that can be expanded should anyone want to review the edits.
